# Filtering rows in data.table while adding a column

Tags: r, data.table

The following returns a data.table with 150 rows

```
library(data.table)
irisDT <- iris %>% data.table
irisDT[Sepal.Width > 3, Petal.Width_rank := row_number(Petal.Width),
     by = "Species"]
```

However, I'm trying to do the subsetting `Sepal.Width > 3` at the same time, instead of doing a "conditional mutate", i.e. I'm trying to do something like

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  filter(Sepal.Width > 3) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(Petal.Width_rank = row_number(Petal.Width))
```

What's the idiomatic way to do this in data.table?

Comment: AFAIK there's a relatively new `frank` function in data.table which you could also use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain your calls:

```
data.table(iris)[
  Sepal.Width > 3
][,
  Petal.Width_rank := rank(Petal.Width, ties="first"), 
  by=Species
][]
```

This produces 67 rows.

Comment: how is `[]` interpreted? can't seem to find it in the documentation

Comment: @organicagave, that is just to force printing of the result.  Because we're modifying the `data.table` with `:=`, the default is not to show the result.  Note this is the same as with any data.frame (try `iris[]`).

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
DT1 <- setDT(iris)[Sepal.Width >3, c(.SD,list(Petal.Width_rank=
                    row_number(Petal.Width))), by=Species] 

 dim(DT1)
 #[1] 67  6
```

In `data.table_1.9.5`, you can also use `frank` with different options for ties (as mentioned by @docendo discimus in the comments)

```
 DT2 <- setDT(iris)[Sepal.Width >3, c(.SD, list(Petal.Width_rank=
            frank(Petal.Width, ties.method='first'))), Species]

 dim(DT2)
 #[1] 67  6
 identical(DT1, DT2)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @Arun Thanks, it can be used, but Brodie already got patented with that method :-)